# Performance improvement for Rails associated model aggregation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a Model called Person and Person has multiple posts. When I want to query post count for each person it takes a long time to process since it needs to iterate over each person and query each posts to get the aggregation.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts
end
```

**Output (JSON):**

```
Person1
  PostsType1Count: 15
  PostsType2Count: 45
Person2
  PostsType3Count: 33
.
.
.
```

I want to calculate all the post count for each Person in a optimum way. What would be the best solution?

Comment: Why does a person have multiple post counts?

Comment: There are different types of posts. I need to calculate them seperatly

Comment: If your post types are pre-defined, add a column for each type of post on Person, and front-load that work. When a post is made, increment the appropriate count, then getting up to date counts is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this, if you have a small and pre-defined set of Types

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :type_1_posts, :class_name => 'Post', :conditions => 'post_type = 1'
  has_many :type_2_posts, :class_name => 'Post', :conditions => 'post_type = 2'
  has_many :type_3_posts, :class_name => 'Post', :conditions => 'post_type = 3'
end
```

Then you can write code that looks like this to get all the data:

```
@all_people = Person.includes(:type_1_posts, :type_2_posts, :type_3_posts).all
```

The **eager loading** of the posts allows the count of each type of post to be available, as well as all the posts of each type.

If you need extra performance for this code, because you perform this query a lot, then you can look into using the Rails **counter cache** mechanism to keep track of the counts of each type on the Person object.

The beauty of Rails here is that your main display code doesn't need to change during this process of making the code faster for reading (adding a counter cache makes adding/deleting posts slower, so you may not want it in all cases).

1. Write initial code
2. Use **eager loading** to make it faster
3. Use **counter cache** to make it even faster

Answer (score 0):

Try this May it will work for you

```
    #In Controller
    @persons = Person.all
    #In View
    @persons.each do |person|
         person.posts.count # It will gives all posts count
         person.posts.collect{|x| true if x.type==1 }.compact.count #If you want to get the post counts based on type
    end
```

Suppose if you want to get any mehods just check in console or debug is person.methods.sort it will give all methods. 
try in rails console  person.posts.methods also it will give types also then check counts based on type. because i dont know which fields in posts model. so check it.

Comment: The problem I faces with the above approach is that we need to iterate over person and get the posts count on each iteration which is costly in performance. I'm searching for a approach that will do the count (May be in database query itself and give the result or more optimized method)